# GCM Push notification if App is closed in mobile (Phonegap Android)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, phonegap-pushplugin

I am using GCM with my phonegap android app. The problem I am facing is, the app is able to receive the notification if its open in mobile, but not able to receive notification if its closed. I have gone through the java code written is working fine. But its not able to communicate with javascript code written for receiving message

```
           public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
             public static final String ME="GCMReceiver";
             public GCMIntentService() {
              super("GCMIntentService");
                }
            private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";
             @Override
             public void onRegistered(Context context, String regId) {
               Log.v(ME + ":onRegistered", "Registration ID arrived!");
               Log.v(ME + ":onRegistered", regId);
               JSONObject json;
                 try
                  {
                json = new JSONObject().put("event", "registered");
               json.put("regid", regId);

               Log.v(ME + ":onRegisterd", json.toString());
             // In this case this is the registration ID
              GCMPlugin.sendJavascript( json );

                   }
                catch( JSONException e)
                        {
                       // No message to the user is sent, JSON failed
                        Log.e(ME + ":onRegisterd", "JSON exception");
                   }
                }

              @Override
              public void onUnregistered(Context context, String regId) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onUnregistered - regId: " + regId);
               }

             @Override
            protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
              Log.d(TAG, "onMessage - context: " + context);


                // Extract the payload from the message
                   Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                   if (extras != null) {
                     try
                       {
                        Log.v(ME + ":onMessage extras ",   extras.getString("message"));                                      

                     JSONObject json;
                     json = new JSONObject().put("event", "message");


             json.put("message", extras.getString("message"));
                json.put("msgcnt", extras.getString("msgcnt"));

               Log.v(ME + ":onMessage ", json.toString());

           GCMPlugin.sendJavascript( json );
             // Send the MESSAGE to the Javascript application
            }
         catch( JSONException e)
        {
             Log.e(ME + ":onMessage", "JSON exception");
              }         
         }


           }

              @Override
              public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
             Log.e(TAG, "onError - errorId: " + errorId);

         }
         }
```

Comment: share the java code written in GCMInterface.java file...

Comment: Thanks Banik! I have added the code please check it above

Comment: I think you are using https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova plugin.There is nowhere written anything how to handle push notifications when the app will go background or being destroyed.In my opinion its better to remove this plugin and use https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin ,otherwise ive to make a drastic change not only to the GCMIntentservice.java but also to the GCMPlugin.java.Its your choice and let me know.

Comment: Instead of making big changes in existing code, I'll try push plugins. In case of any problem I'll let you know @Banik Thanks!

Comment: [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) is the latest and it works very well. @Banik You could add that as an answer.

Comment: added it as an answer and thnks.

Comment: Hey Banik I have used PushPlugins as you told. Now notifications are working fine. Now a small issue is I want to save the data coming with GCM message. When the app is running I am able to save but when it is closed I am not able to do the same. As I observed it is not going inside 'message' case inside javascript code. How can I handle it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using [GCMPlugin](https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova) plugin.There is nowhere written anything how to handle push notifications when the app will go background or being destroyed.In my opinion its better to remove this plugin and use [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) ,otherwise you have to make a drastic change not only to the GCMIntentservice.java but also to the GCMPlugin.java.